# powershell or .net - how to receive domain accounts with domain names

Tags: .net, powershell, quest

I was asking few days ago how to combine Lotus Notes data with data from Active Directory. I was sure, that there will be no problem with retrieving user accounts from AD, but actually, there is one problem. I used the Get-QADUser to receive user names, but as I later realize, there are no user accounts. I have only winxp and win2003 server, so I can't use Active Directory Module for PowerShell and it's Search-ADAccount cmdlet.

I'm trying Get-QADUser, but with no effect. This command lists domain names in this form:

```
Markus Elen                user            CN=Markus Elen,OU=Users,OU=CENTRAL,DC=pb,DC=sk
```

but I need name of user and his domain account.

Is it possible to do it with QADUser or other cmdlet other than Search-ADAccount? Thank you!

Comment: Post how are you using get-qaduser and more detail on what you want achieve.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused: you're trying to use Get-QADUser to retrieve something other than a user account because you have no user accounts? Or do you mean no accounts that match a certain search or other criteria? What exactly are you trying to get?

Comment: Sorry for cunfusing question. The Get-QADUsser displays user names, but I need user accounts. I was trying all 27 examples from help file, but with no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-QADUser` returns an object with lots of properties, which does include the user account name. Try

```
Get-QADUser markus |fl
```

to see them all. You probably want either

```
Get-QADUser markus |ft Name, LogonName
Get-QADUser markus |ft Name, NTAccountName
```

although if you're reading these programmatically you should accept the objects directly from Get-QADUser and query the properties directly from them.

Comment: Meanwhile I found that Get-QADUser | object Name, SamAccountName is working, but your Get-QADUser | ft Name, LogonName is working too! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell lets you query AD natively by using the [ADSISEARCHER] type shortcut (it wraps the System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher type). Here's an example of getting all users from your default domain.

```
$searcher = [adsisearcher]'(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)" 
$searcher.FindAll()
```